# How to collect different strings' occurrence number within a unique txt document using python?

Tags: python

I want to collect different strings'(which are from another txt document) occurrence number within a unique txt document. For example, here's the 1.txt document contains different strings, and 2.txt is the unique document:

```
假
间
见
解
就
举
绝
堪
克
类
怜
```

And the count_number code is here:

```
def countnumber(filename, stringname):
    with open (filename, 'r+') as f:
        txt = f.readlines()
        txt2 = ''.join(text)
        count_number = txt2.count(stringname)
        record_file = dirroot + "record.txt"
        with open(record_file, 'a+') as f2:
            f.write(stringname)
            f.write(str(count_number))
            f.write('\n')
        f.close()
```

I don't want to input string one by one to collect number so i try to use iteration, here's the code:

```
with open("2.txt", 'r+') as f:
    content = ''.join(f.readlines())
    with open('1.txt', 'r+') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            count_number = content.count(line)
            print count_number
```

But the output is frustrated:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

What's wrong within my code?

Comment: Try `content.count(line.strip())`

Comment: @Kevin Oh my God!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! How could you do that??

Comment: How could I guess what the problem might be? Unexpected whitespace when reading the lines of a file is a pretty common problem.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you Kevin. Love you so much.